# Odd light switch

Tags: electrical, switch

Our (former) painter painted over all of our outlets and switches and so I am swapping them out. All was going well until I came across an odd light switch that is puzzling. First off, it is for a single light above my desk and is not a 3way. The front has a shiny metal plate - the back is black plastic and there are no screws - just two black wires coming out of the back. The switch is hard to turn off - I really want to replace it ASAP. Suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please add a photo of what the switch looks like and what the electrical box innards look like.

Comment: Be very careful with switches that have 3 or more wires (not counting ground).  Also be on the watch for receptacles with little tabs removed between the screws, learn what the tabs look like and what it looks like when they're gone.

Comment: "wires coming out of the back" means one thing to me - the device was wired using what some call the "back stab" terminals.  The use of these is NOT recommended.  There are probably screws or at least threaded holes (where the screws would normally live) on the side.  My guess is all you need is a standard SPST switch.  As others suggested, pics (good ones) would help.